# How to handle a link only answer to an off-topic question

Tags: support, flags

I just came across a question which reads as follows:

> I want to make a [type of] application in [language] in which there will be [specifics] which technologies should i use. please give me some input.

I flagged the question as off-topic, because it clearly is, but then someone provided an answer. Their answer is mostly just a link to some library or something they recommend. It legitimately answers the question, but it is pretty much a link only answer AND the question is clearly off topic. How are we supposed to flag this sort of answer? Or should I use a downvote?

Comment: Flag as VLQ please.

Comment: An additional downvote for the answer would make it easier to deal with it in case of closure of the question, be it manually or performed by the roomba script.

Comment: Murder. Definitely murder.

Comment: Just don't comment, unless you're ready to face the consequences. :)